# Unwanted symbol in entry field with Onepage Checkout

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, input

Got another strange problem, whenever the checkout page is called the postcode field is immediately populated with a single '*'.

Tried several workarounds including using jQuery to try and strip it out but nothing seems to work.

Further information found, only occurs with guest checkout, seems to be a bizarre default somewhere. As well as this, as far as we can tell the issue started occurring after setting our region to require postcode (Unfortunately does not revert with the setting.)

Does anyone have any idea which file this might be occurring in?

Comment: Are you using a custom theme ?

Comment: Just a (personally) altered version of the Luma theme, as far as I'm aware I haven't made any changes to checkout files.

Comment: Does it happen when you switch back to the original Luma theme ? Any extension affecting the checkout/customer process ? Affecting all browsers ?

Comment: Problem only seems to occur in Chrome after some testing, the only extension used for the checkout process has been used since inception and  does not seem to be the cause, as it's a more recent issue. The theme itself is altered directly as opposed to using a separate theme, so I cannot switch.